# To search a particular file in PDF document using Java

Tags: java, pdf

Hi I have a PDF file and I need to search a particular string in that. I tried various methods, and I am able to read all the contents in PDF file but unable to find a particular string.

[image]

Here in this file, I need to search string such as Telephone, Garbage, Rent etc individually.

Could you please help me?

I have the below code for reading the file.

```
public class PDFBoxReader {

private PDFParser parser;
private PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
private PDDocument pdDoc ;
private COSDocument cosDoc ;

private String Text ;
private String filePath;
private File file;

public PDFBoxReader() {

}
public String ToText() throws IOException
{
   this.pdfStripper = null;
   this.pdDoc = null;
   this.cosDoc = null;

   file = new File("D:\\report.pdf");
   parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));

   parser.parse();
   cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
   pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
   pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
   pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();

   pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
   pdfStripper.setEndPage(10);
   // reading text from page 1 to 10
   // if you want to get text from full pdf file use this code
   // pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());

   Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
   return Text;
  }

public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
    this.filePath = filePath;
}

}
```

It would be great if someone could help me with a code that searches for a particular string. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand. You have a string now containing the whole content of a range of pages or even a single page. What keeps you from searching that string for your particular string?

Comment: If you could see the PDF, I need to get the column next to that particular string. Say telephone, I need to get the next column that has value 0. It applies to all such string.

Comment: So essentially you want to extract structured data from a PDF. This usually is difficult. Cam you share your sample document as PDF instead of as Image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `String.indexOf("substring")` with `String` being what is returned from your `ToText()` method, and `substring` the string you wish to search for. (Side note, the custom in Java is camel-case methods, which would be `toText()` in this case.)

This method should find the first index of the entered substring in your long `String` of text. So you could do `String.indexOf("Telephone")` to find the first occurrence of the word Telephone in your `String`.

If you want the stuff directly after that substring, the index would simply be `String.indexOf("substring")+"substring".length()`

You can even find the next occurrence (or the next after that) with another variation of this method `String.indexOf("substring", indexOfLastOccurrence+"substring".length)`

Example:

```
String myPDF = ToText();
int rentIndex = myPDF.indexOf("Rent")+"Rent".length();
String rent = myPDF.substring(rentIndex); //Find 1st occurrence of "Rent" and get info after it
rent = rent.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex); //Get endIndex-beginIndex characters after rent. (I assume you only want like a few numbers afterwards or something.)
//process rent e.g. Integer.parseInt(rent) or something

rentIndex = myPDF.indexOf("Rent",rentIndex)+"Rent".length();
rent = myPDF.substring(rentIndex); //Next occurrence of "Rent"
//Repeat to find the next occurrence, and the one after that. (Until rentIndex gets set to a negative, indicating that no more occurrences exist.)
```

Both methods can be found in the Java API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: This is basically sample code... But sure I'll add a block